# AngularJS ng-repeat orderby doesn't work properly with greek words

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting, sql-order-by, angularjs-ng-repeat

It appears that when I use the orderBy filter inside ng-repeat, in order to sort alphabetically an array of objects by some property, the results I get are wrong.
Specifically, orderBy places first all strings starting with letters with accent such as Ά, Έ, Ή, Ί and so on, ignoring their position in the alphabet. 
In my example, I created an array of objects

```
$scope.words = [
{id: 1, name: "Αντώνης"},
{id: 2, name: "Ίκαρος"},
{id: 3, name: "Έλλη"},
{id: 4, name: "Βασίλης"},
{id: 5, name: "Γιάννης"},
{id: 6, name: "Δημήτρης"},
{id: 7, name: "Ζήσης"},
{id: 8, name: "Ηρακλής"},
{id: 9, name: "Θανάσης"},
];
```

And used the ng-repeat directive to create a list:

```
<div ng-repeat="w in words | orderBy:'name'">{{w.name}}</div>
```

The sorted results I get are:

```
Έλλη, Ίκαρος, Αντώνης, Βασίλης, Γιάννης, Δημήτρης, Ζήσης, Ηρακλής, Θανάσης
```

While the correct ones would be:

```
Αντώνης, Βασίλης, Γιάννης, Δημήτρης, Έλλη, Ζήσης, Ηρακλής, Θανάσης, Ίκαρος
```

See fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fincher64/mn98twm7/).

Is there anyway to correct this behavior? How could I create my own orderBy filter?

Comment: you can provide your own predicate/comparator function to orderBy filer. See https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.7/docs/api/ng/filter/orderBy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your words are not sorted properly when their are accented.

You could use a map to remove all the accents, and use a service like this one:

```
.factory('diacritics',['diacriticsMap',function(diacriticsMap){//should inject diacriticsMap
var removeDiacritics=function (str) {
        var letters = str.split("");
        var newStr = "";
        for(var i=0; i< letters.length; i++) {
            newStr += letters[i] in diacriticsMap ? diacriticsMap[letters[i]] : letters[i];
        }
        return newStr;
    };
return {
    remove:removeDiacritics
};
```

where the map is a constant like this:

`constant('diacriticsMap',{
    "A":"A",
    "Ⓐ":"A",
    "Ａ":"A",
    "À":"A",
...
})`

You could then sort non accented words, which would definitely work.

Comment: I actually have a map with all the letters of different alphabets, but I did not see the point of including it whole in my answer. However, if you go for this option, I could send it to you by some other means

Comment: I used a similar approach to resolve this issue. I created a filter that replaces accented letters with the normal ones, and a controller method that is used as the orderBy function and utilizes the filter. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fincher64/mn98twm7/3/)